# MATLAB not loading- java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: linux, matlab, jdk, jre, fedora-17

The installation itself was giving an error: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: data starting at 0 is in unknown format`

but when I deselected Aeromodeling toolbox then Matlab got successfully installed.

When I tried to run it I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mathworks/instwiz/arch/ArchGuiFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathworks.instwiz.arch.ArchGuiFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.mathworks.activationclient.ActivationApplication.  Program will exit.
```

I have openJDK 1.7 and openJDK-devel 1.7 installed in 64bit FC17. I reinstalled openJDK but still the problem persists.

is there any extra dependency?? is there a problem of linking with java? How to solve this problem

Comment: please let me know how to fix this.. the same version of Matlab works in my other system..

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling MATLAB? Which error did you face when installing?

Comment: i tried reinstalling matlab.. the initial installation failed because of some dependencies of Aero toolbox.. 

this was the error `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: data starting at 0 is in unknown format`

so without the aero toolbox it installed but wont load.. i am pretty convinced that there is a problem with loading jre.. no idea how to fix it

Comment: installation still fails when i select aero toolbox

Comment: The line `Could not find the main class: com.mathworks.activationclient.ActivationApplication` might indicate that you chose a wrong activation method? Anyway, you might have a look at this thread: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=284091

Comment: I didnt get the activation propmt.. the file called activate_matlab.sh also doesn't run and gives the same error. deactivate_matlab.sh also gives the same error.

Comment: Have you tried with the `-javadir  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/` option when installing, as suggested in the link above?

Comment: yes.. doesnt work still

Comment: I read that `libXp.so.6` is required for MATLAB to install, check if it is installed, otherwise `yum install libXp.x86_64`

Comment: libXp is installed.. I read that Matlab is not compliant with openJDK7.. is it advisable to install openJDK6 along with openJDK7 ??

Comment: If you have solved the problem by now, please post your solution as an answer here. If not, I would recommend you to contact Mathworks support.